# Can I apply for an EB-4 religious worker visa right after getting an R1 visa?

Tags: usa, immigration

**I completed 2 years of working in November**, I got the R1 in October. There is a stipulation that the person needs to have at least 2 years of experience before filing EB4. My query is, can I file petition now or should I wait for 2 years?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have 2 years of experience *in R-1 status*. You only need to have 2 years of experience in a qualifying religious worker position *either inside or outside the US*. This is mentioned here: https://www.uscis.gov/working-in-the-united-states/permanent-workers/employment-based-immigration-fourth-preference-eb-4/special-immigrant-religious-workers .

The [federal regulations](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/204.5#m_4) further clarify that the qualifying experience, if obtained in the US, must have been "in lawful immigration status". While I suppose this will typically be R-1 status, there are also other possible statuses the person could have, that would allow them to take up qualifying religious employment prior to applying for an EB4 green card.

Since R-1 status falls into the dual intent grey area, a lawyer may advise you to wait 90 days after your most recent admission in R-1 status or effective date of change of status to R-1, prior to beginning the I-360/I-485 process, in order to avoid appearances of misrepresentation.

Comment: I was on f1 and OPT visa prior to getting an R1.